# Insert special characters in DB2 database

Tags: java, sql, db2

I am having `database in DB2` that works fine with `insertion` of normal text with `java`.

But as some `special characters` occurs like `Mise à jour des référentiels liés` then problem 
comes in insertion of data.

Please tell what actually the problem is with insertion of such type of data and how can we do insertion of such data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help if you said what the problem was.

Comment: What do expect to happen?
What happens instead?

Answer (score 2):

The problem (I think, since you haven't specified on you created your database) is that you haven't created a database that supports UTF-8.

[IBM DB2 UDB (Universal Database) supports UTF-8 and UCS-2.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/t0004617.htm)

When creating a database, you can set `CODESET` to be of type UTF-8, as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname USING CODESET UTF-8
```

Alternatively, you can set [CCSID](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/c0004821.htm) on your table (or table column). For UTF-8, the CCSID = 1208, while UCS-2, CCSID = 1200.

This [IBM article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.char/src/tpc/db2z_createunicodetable.htm) shows you which data column each CCSID is associated to when assigning a table as Unicode.